# 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, error, error-handling, dll-embedding

While running Sharepoint Client Side Scripting in Visual Studio getting error at the end of **ExecuteQuery()**

> It throws an unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden.

How can I resolve this ?

[image]

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759278/visual-studio-2013-accessing-sharepoint-online

Comment: am using Visual Studio 2015 does it matter ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify 2 things:-

- Check whether the site you are trying to access is really exists? URL is valid?
- The Credential you are using to authenticate must have permission to access the web which you are trying to access. Verify once by using to same credential via web browser.

Comment: yes am using really existing URL, I could able to log in via web browser

Answer (score -1):

in app.config file add the below line worked for me:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials ="true"></defaultProxy>
  </system.net
```